# VIsual Studio 2012_error LNK2001

Tags: c++

Im using Visual Studio 2012 to compile my project and I am getting these errors.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__FTCreateFaceTracker@4
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__FTCreateImage@0
```

What is the solution for this errors? Please guide me

Comment: "Can anyone please help me." is  correctly answerable with "yes" or "no", would that help you? Ask specific, direct questions.  No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)), therefore "Thank you" should never be part of a good question.
It is not impolite to leave that out but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix